# How solve: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, valueerror

I am making a function to categorize data, but i am recieving this error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\gabri\Downloads\credit_scoring_eng.csv')


def economic_class(valor):
    if valor<=16000:
        return 'economic_class'
    elif valor<=24000:
        return 'executive_class'
    elif valor<=32000:
        return 'first_class'
    else:
        return 'five_star_class'
df['class'] = df['total_income'].apply(economic_class)
```

Here is the complete error:

```
Cell In [172], line 3
      1 # Criar coluna com categorias
      2 print(df['total_income'])
----> 3 df['class'] = df['total_income'].apply(economic_class)

File c:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:4433, in Series.apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwargs)
   4323 def apply(
   4324     self,
   4325     func: AggFuncType,
   (...)
   4328     **kwargs,
   4329 ) -> DataFrame | Series:
   4330     """
   4331     Invoke function on values of Series.
   4332 
   (...)
   4431     dtype: float64
   4432     """
-> 4433     return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()

File c:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:1082, in SeriesApply.apply(self)
   1078 if isinstance(self.f, str):
   1079     # if we are a string, try to dispatch
...
   1528         f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1529         "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1530     )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I already try a lot of solutions of this error on internet, but didnt work ;-;

I was expecting make a new column to the dataframe.

[image: df.head()]

Comment: Can you share `df.head()` please?

Comment: of course! @cmauck10
:D

Comment: Everything you have here checks out. Make sure the `economic_class()` function is defined and that all entries in the `total_income` column are floats.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below. It's also helpful to provide either dummy data or a sample of your data(not an image).

Without data provided, below is a sample you can adjust that works

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name':['Bob','Kyle','Kevin','Dave'],
        'Value':[1000,20000,40000,30000]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
display(df)


def economic_class(valor):
    if valor<=16000:
        valor = 'economic_class'
        
    elif valor<=24000:
        valor = 'executive_class'
        
    elif valor<=32000:
        valor = 'first_class'
        
    else:
        valor = 'five_star_class'
        
    return valor

df['class'] = df['Value'].apply(economic_class)
display(df)
```

Comment: same error in the code :v

Comment: @Riuk2252 updated answer and put the full example with dummy data. If you provide your sample data it will be easier to back into. However, the above runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is correct. I think the problem is apply. Can you try this:

```
def economic_class(valor):
    if valor<=16000:
        return 'economic_class'
    elif valor<=24000:
        return 'executive_class'
    elif valor<=32000:
        return 'first_class'
    else:
        return 'five_star_class'
df['class'] = df['total_income'].apply(lambda x: economic_class(x))
```